# AudioCapture[] not capturing sound from my Focusrite input

Tags: sound, windows

Windows 10:

```
$AudioInputDevices
{"Focusrite USB (Focusrite USB Au", "Microphone (B525 HD Webcam)"}
```

In windows settings I can see that the "test your microphone" line is reacting to my input through the Focusrite USB and

```
AudioCapture[AudioInputDevice -> $AudioInputDevices[[1]]]
```

returns the appropriate recording box but is unresponsive to Focusrite input.

Comment: It works on MMA12.1 Windows 10

Comment: One additional note, I have the sound running through Guitar Rig for real time effects. Do I need to capture it coming out that program?